# react funcion <br> is not working in this <p>

Tags: html, css, reactjs, newline

I have search and tried much now but nothing works to get a new line here.
This is the React function

Really basic problem I guess because i'm quite new on this but please advice.
someone suggested to have this:

```
.new-line {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

in the css but that did not work either . Can this be about using having a js file-extensions?

```
import React from "react";
import Badge from "../elements/Badge";
import Resume from "../../resume.json";

function AboutMe() {
  return (
    <section className="section has-background-link" id="aboutMe">
      <div className="container has-text-centered">
        <figure className="image container is-180x180">
          <img
            width="180px"
            height="180px"
            src={Resume.basics.picture}
            alt={Resume.basics.name}
            className="is-rounded"
            onError={(e)=>{e.target.onerror = null; e.target.src=Resume.basics.x_pictureFallback}}
          />
        </figure>
        <p className="subtitle is-4 has-text-white has-text-weight-bold">
          {Resume.basics.x_title}
        </p>
        <p className="subtitle is-5 has-text-white has-text-weight-light summary-text">
          {"test Give me a new line now<br>yes I love it"}
        </p>
        <div className="container interests">
          <div className="field is-grouped is-grouped-multiline has-text-centered">
            {Resume.interests.map((value, index) => {
              return (
                <Badge key={index} text={value.name} faIcon={value.x_icon} />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default AboutMe;
```

I only use one css

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.is-180x180{
    height: 180px;
    width: 180px;
}
.skill-list > li{
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.has-bg-image {
    background-image: url('../images/GretaThunberg collage2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.bulma-image {
    width: 200px;
}
.interests {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.summary-text {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 36em;
}
.skill-percentage {
    float: right;
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=0"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#3273DC" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://josecoelho93.pt" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is my personal website. You can find information about my experience, skills and articles I have written." />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bulma-timeline.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./images/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.0/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-134602535-1"></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-134602535-1');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.jsdiaries.com/how-to-create-a-new-line-in-jsx-and-reactjs/ check this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems to me that this is not a `React.js` question, but an HTML/CSS one. I would recommend you try to focus searching for *Newline in HTML / CSS* instead of mentioning React, since it has nothing to do with this not working. I can assure you that the `.js` extension has nothing to do with it though :)

Also, try copying the HTML into separate `.html` file, without React, and debug from there if it is easier for you - you will also see nothing has changed and there is no effect from React whatsoever.

I would recommend experimenting with `margin-bottom` `padding-bottom` as well, just to give you some tips. If you want to, you could provide us with a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can take a look at a live demo.

**EDIT: After further inspection, there might be a JavaScript mistake I did not see at first**

I would also try the following change:

```
<p>{"test Give me a new line now<br>yes I love it"}</p>
```

Change it to:

```
<p>test Give me a new line now<br />yes I love it</p>
```

You cannot pass HTML / React elements inside a string like that, since they won't be taken in consideration as anything else than string.

Comment: Thanks That worked. This feels like a bug workaround

Comment: @portplays in react, there are self closing tags, such as `<a />` `<br />` and others, just to clear it up for you - that is the JSX syntax

Comment: I have not seen the version with a space <br \> I read it's for XHTML thanks good to know

Answer (score 0):

Without digging to deep, and piggy backing on Antonio's answer. You can isolate the problem with a console.log statement in your browser:

```
console.log("test Give me a new line now\nyes I love it")
```

What is being down is you need to replace the 
 tag because you are in a sanitized text string and replace it with a newline `\n` character.

Depending on the template engine there may be ways to inject HTML into the text string but it seems like a newline is all you are after.

Answer (score -2):

try using back tick...
It is not ideal but will work fine